# SQL query to get list of months till now by entering year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I have to display all the months of present year till now when year parameter is entered.

For example if I enter 2016, then all months till September should be shown.

How to achieve this? Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get what the parameter is used for.  Your description seems to be to get the months from the current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below script.

```
;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT cast(@year+'-01-01' as date)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date)
    from months
    where  DATEADD(month,1,date)<= case when @year=YEAR(getdate()) THEN CAST(getdate() as date) ELSE cast(@year+'-12-31' as date) END
)
select Datename(month,date) [Month] from months
```

**Output** :

[image]

Comment: But what if 2015 is given as parameter? IT will still show all months from 2015 and all from 2016. How to restrict that?

Comment: what is your expected output when you give year as 2015?

Comment: just added a case statement in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy with a recursive CTE:

```
with m as (
      select datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1) as mm
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, m.mm)
      from m
      where m.mm < getdate()
     )
select m.*
from mm;
```

It is unclear to me what the parameter is used for.  This gets the months from this year.

Comment: I get  "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int." when I try this

Comment: @GuidoG . . . Ouch.  That would be the condition in the `where` clause.

Comment: last line should be "from m;"